# Which function denotes the energy of thermal motion within a system?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In thermodynamics, the heat $Q$ is defined as a type of energy in transfer, and is not a state function, which function denotes the energy of thermal motion within a system?

1) $TS$, (there is a contradictory, for an idea gas, $dU=TdS-pdV=C_vdT$)

2) Enthalpy $H$, ($H=U-Yx+pV =TS+pV+\sum_j\mu_jN_j$)

3) Neither of the two, the function has not been well defined,

4) The function cannot be defined.

5) Others.

Comment: Can you *define* thermal motion for arbitrary systems?

Comment: @ ACuriousMind, temperature $T$ is the intensive variable that describes the strength of the energy distribution of thermal motion, so the question can also be considered as: which extensive variable is paired with the intensive variable $T$?

Comment: That temperature describes motion is not true for arbitrary systems. Pure spin systems have a temperature although they can't even move.

Comment: $\frac32 NkT$ for translational motion as well as appropriately weighted multiples of $NkT$ for vibrational and rotational motion as long as quantum effects can be neglegted (ie the spacing of the discrete energy levels is much smaller than $kT$)

Comment: @ACuriousMind, Does spin relate to chemical potential, and $\partial \mu/\partial T$ denotes the energy conversion between Gibbs free energy and the energy of thermal motion?

Comment: @Christoph, is there a thermodynamical function that can be applied to arbitrary system? such as a photon gas, $U=3pV \approx 3\cdot 0.9NkT$.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Temperature or Internal energy $U$ would be roughly what you're after. Or enthalpy $H$. But you'll need more variables to define the state of the system (# depends on how complex it is).

At equilibrium, temperature and knowledge of kind stuff (gas, solid etc.) you're dealing with would let you figure out the distribution of thermal energy in the various modes (translation, rotation, vibration and electronic for an ideal gas).  For a relatively cool gas (warmer if a noble gas) most of the energy will be in translation.  As it get hotter more will go into other modes.

For the details of those calculations, you'll want to look at statistical mechanics.